# docker: Error: No such container: jmar71n/freepbx

Tags: server, login, root, docker, container

how do I [login](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16840409/262852) to a [container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38464549/262852) as [root](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28721699/262852)?

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu              latest              20c44cd7596f        2 days ago          123MB
hello-world         latest              725dcfab7d63        2 weeks ago         1.84kB
jmar71n/freepbx     latest              8dda2a58fde1        19 months ago       1.54GB
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
a2e7e9f60643        hello-world         "bash"              2 minutes ago       Created                                        laughing_knuth
b616192b64f4        ubuntu              "bash"              5 minutes ago       Exited (0) 5 minutes ago                       nifty_kowalevski
28237032f2d3        jmar71n/freepbx     "/sbin/my_init"     24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes                                  wonderful_wilson
54c683990ccc        jmar71n/freepbx     "/sbin/my_init"     26 minutes ago      Up 26 minutes                                  modest_yalow
a91a6dcb8436        jmar71n/freepbx     "/sbin/my_init"     2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                     gallant_noether
ac53b46b768e        ubuntu              "bash"              24 hours ago        Exited (0) 24 hours ago                        mystifying_murdock
b59af1daa216        hello-world         "/hello"            24 hours ago        Exited (0) 24 hours ago                        flamboyant_curie
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo docker exec -u 0 -it jmar71n/freepbx bash
Error: No such container: jmar71n/freepbx
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo docker exec -u 0 -it 8dda2a58fde1 bash
Error: No such container: 8dda2a58fde1
thufir@dur:~$
```

I can sorta login to one of the containers:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo docker run -it ubuntu bash
root@b616192b64f4:/# exit
exit
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo docker run -it jar71n/freepbx bash
Unable to find image 'jar71n/freepbx:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: repository jar71n/freepbx not found: does not exist or no pull access.
See 'docker run --help'.
thufir@dur:~$
```

although the `ubuntu` image seems quite minimal.  Want to login to any of the above containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems you are spelling wrong the container name:

jar71n != jmar71n

Comment: what's the difference betweent the `exec` and `run` above?  It looked like `exec` was the way to login -- will have to re-check that.

Comment: Not sure, I had used docker just for learning and fun but I think you only can exec things into running containers.

Comment: If you don't explicitly tell docker to run something in background onto the container it finish itself after you call it so you need to run it again to log in